# using dictConfig in python logging, need to create a logger with a different file than defined in dict.

Tags: python, logging

I have a LOG_SETTINGS dict that looks like:

```
LOG_SETTINGS = {
'version': 1,
'handlers': {
    'console': {
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        'level': 'INFO',
        'formatter': 'detailed',
        'stream': 'ext://sys.stdout',
    },
    'file': {
        'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
        'level': 'INFO',
        'formatter': 'detailed',
        'filename': '/tmp/junk.log',
        'mode': 'a',
        'maxBytes': 10485760,
        'backupCount': 5,
    },

},
'formatters': {
    'detailed': {
        'format': '%(asctime)s %(module)-17s line:%(lineno)-4d ' \
        '%(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
    },
    'email': {
        'format': 'Timestamp: %(asctime)s\nModule: %(module)s\n' \
        'Line: %(lineno)d\nMessage: %(message)s',
    },
},
'loggers': {
    'extensive': {
        'level':'DEBUG',
        'handlers': ['file',]
        },
}
}
```

In my code I do the following:

```
logging.config.dictConfig(LOG_SETTINGS)

logger = logging.getLogger('extensive')
logger.info("This is from Runner {0}".format(self.default_name))

logger2 = logging.getLogger('extensive')
logfile = logging.FileHandler("test.log")
logger2.addHandler(logfile)

logger2.info("This is from Runner {0} to the new   file.".format(self.default_name))
```

But the output is still written to the original log file defined in LOG_SETTINGS. What I am looking for is to have the ability to say: logger2.replaceHandler(logfile) rather than addHandler.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

firstly, empty your logger handlers `logger.handlers = []` then add another handler.

```
logger2 = logging.getLogger('extensive')
logfile = logging.FileHandler("test.log")
logger2.handlers = []
logger2.addHandler(logfile)
```

Comment: Thank you. Another thing I found is the `removeHandler` [link](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.removeHandler), but I'm not sure what the 'hdlr' is? .

Comment: for `handler`,it is a logging handler object.