# Which module should contain logging.config.dictConfig(my_dictionary)? What about my_dictionary?

Tags: python, logging, dictionary, module

This is all Python. I am still learning...

I have written two modules for my Python application: `Module1` and `Module2`.
I need to send my logging results to three different files. `Module1` sends to `setup.log` and `setupdetails.log` files and `Module2` sends to `runall.log`
Module2 is the application I run. Within it is an import statement that calls Module1.

Because I have configured my logging in a `my_dictionary`, which one of the modules should contain the dictionary? Which one of the modules should contain the `logging.config.dictConfig(my_dictionary)` function?

Do you know of anywhere I could find a good script with an example of how to use `dictConfig`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I just finally figured it out.

It all works well if one puts the dictionary in the child module `Module 1` (and set `Propagate: True`).

```
MY_DICTIONARY = {
'version': 1,              
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'formatters': {
    'verbose': {
        'format': '%(levelname)-8s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s',
        'datefmt': '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S'

    },
    'standard': {
        'format': '%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(name)s: %(message)s',
        'datefmt': '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S'

    },
    'simple': {
        'format': '%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
        'datefmt': '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S'
    }
#etc.
}
```

}

Followed by the following calls:

```
logging.config.dictConfig(MY_DICTIONARY)
vmrunalllogger = logging.getLogger('VMRunAll_Python_Logger')
```

Then in Module 2 (the parent module), have this:

```
logging.config.dictConfig(MY_DICTIONARY)
mylogger = logging.getLogger('RunAll_Logger')
```

I could not find specific examples that showed two different modules logging to multiple files like mine is doing, but information from multiple sources like the following helped:

1. [From the Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html)
2. [Another question on Stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931423/using-dictconfig-in-python-logging-need-to-create-a-logger-with-a-different-fil)
3. [And the examples of in the cookbook](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html)

Comment: Is 'VMRunAll_Python_Logger' defined in your 'loggers' section of the config or is it just the module name?

Answer (score 2):

For dictConfig:

```
import logging.config
logging.config.dictConfig() #Your method.
```

In terms of what you need to do, it might be easier if you posted some of your code.

[Some documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.dictConfig)

[An Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7507842/2620328)

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation on import logging.config I tried my code at the end of the day last night and had an `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'config'` message. What you suggested to import happens to be the solution to the `AttributeError`.
As to the example, I had seen it already. But thanks. Let me come back with fresh news in just a second.